# How can I configure Airflow to read DAGs from a GCS bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, airflow

Before I start, please do not suggest I use Google Composer. My company has already decided that this solution is not appropriate for us.

I have created a small Compute VM in GCP to host an Airflow instance, and I am wanting to store our DAGs in a GCS bucket. I have created the bucket, and updated the airflow.cfg file to point to it. When I run `airflow webserver` the terminal output says that it is filling the DagBag from the path given, and there are no errors, however Airflow does not find my DAGs.

Am I missing a configuration step somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Airflow can't read the DAG files natively from a GCS Bucket.

You will have to use something like [GCSFuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) to mount a GCS Bucket to your VM. And use the mounted path as Airflow DAGs folder.

For example:

Bucket Name: `gs://test-bucket`
Mount Path: `/airflow-dags`

Update your `airflow.cfg` file to read DAGs from `/airflow-dags` on the VM where the GCS Bucket is mounted.

Comment: I was worried that would be the case. Thanks - I'll test it out in the morning.

Comment: Be careful about the billing. Gcsfuse can generate lot of request class a and generate extra billing.